# identify song information from mp3 id3v2 tags

Tags: javascript, mp3, id3

i already have mp3 binary data, i just want to know how can i extract info from it. v1 is easy, take last 128 characters and you are done. but v2 has variable length. documentation says that tag size will be in header but i was unable to find it in any song i tested.

but anyways i simply want to extract album and artist info.. jsut these two, with javascript. lets take for simplicity sake that i have first 2000 bytes of a Taylor swift song in a variable (below is the actual binary data of a song):

```
ID3!vTYER2010TIT2
Last KissMCDI¬E+96+4484+918B+E800+12F4B+1A636+1EC24+23A8E+2905F+2F7DD+33868+3914B+3D931+44555+4A27BTRCK13TCON(2)CountryPRIVPeakValue¡PRIVAverageLevel{ TPE2
Taylor SwiftPRIV)WM/MediaClassSecondaryIDPRIV'WM/MediaClassPrimaryID¼}`Ñ#ãâK¡H¤*(DPRIVWM/ProviderAMGPRIVWM/WMContentIDÇ1t>êDëþëPRIV"WM/WMCollectionID   ¨F}âH"Y#7 ÈPRIV'WM/WMCollectionGroupID  ¨F}âH"Y#7 ÈTPUBBig MachinePRIVWM/UniqueFileIdentifierAMGa_id=R  2026672;AMGp_id=P   816977;AMGt_id=T 22057912TALB
Speak NowTPE1
Taylor SwiftTLEN369120ÿûà@üK
```

now i can easily locate the album and artist name (last two lines). and i can also find where the data begins with js pretty easily. just locate `TALB` and `TPE1`. simple. but how in the world do i know where the data ends..? they may or may not be adjacent to each other in other songs. they may or may not be uppercase. how do all the other libraries figure out where the data ends?

also there is no 'size' in the beginning as the documentation suggests.

**EDIT** can anyone help me out please? i really need this

Comment: Seems like the ID3 header is missing part way. Any chance you can share the file, and we could take a look at it?

Comment: @TankorSmash from file you mean the audio file or the code that extracts the id3 header? As the answer by J. Andrew Laughlin tells, all characters are not printable so maybe that's why the data is incomplete?

Comment: I meant the audiofile, I currently use Python, and I could take a look at it, and see if there actually is missing data, or it's just unprintable. Unless you got it handled, then you're all set?

Comment: yes, i actually dropped the idea of parsing id3v2, i am only using id3v1.

Comment: Oh that's a shame, I was getting ready to try to help you out, since I'm trying to do the same thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The binary sample you show is missing some data.  An ID3 version 2.4 tag frame header is 10 bytes in length and consists of the following fields:

- ID -- 4 bytes (e.g. TIT2)
- Size -- 4 bytes (is sync-safe in versions >= 2.4)
- Flags -- 2 bytes

The size field tells you how many bytes of data are in that particular frame.  Similarly the actual tag header is 10 bytes as well:

- ID -- 3 bytes (always ID3)
- Version -- 2 bytes (major version and revision.  e.g. 0x04 0x00 indicates a 2.4.0 tag version)
- Flags -- 1 byte
- Size -- 4 bytes (is sync-safe in versions >= 2.3)

See: http://id3.org/id3v2.4.0-structure

Once your script has the binary data, you can parse these size fields to determine the size of the complete tag as well as the size of each frame.  Once you get to this point you're going to run into sync-safe integers.

See: [Why are there Synchsafe Integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5223025/why-are-there-synchsafe-integer/5652842#5652842)

Comment: yes! i thought that too, but that is the actual out put. i pasted it from the output screen itself. and to my surprise i tried a bunch of songs from a variety of albums and none of them had a 10 byte header.. maybe it is something specs dictate but songs dont usually follow?

Comment: Also as far as i am able to understand from your answer and from the documentation, every tag frame (eg artist name, album name, etc) is predefined identifier which is stated in the header.. right? like this is the header `other header info [some 'predefined identifier'] other header info` and the tag body `[that 'predefined identifier'] frame info` am i correct?

Comment: Yes.  Each frame is of a specific type.  For example a frame with an ID of TPE1 typically represents the artist.  There are quite a few frame types.  See: http://id3.org/id3v2.4.0-frames.  If you're using Linux or OS X, Bulk ID3 will show exactly what your tags contain.  See: http://sourceforge.net/projects/bulkid3.  Keep in mind it's currently an alpha.  Also, copying and pasting won't necessarily provide all the data, since many values are not printable.  You need a good hex editor to view the actual data.

Comment: thanks for the ref links. can you point me to a good hex editor in javascript. I am currently using FileSystem API's `readAsBinaryString` to get the binary data.. and chrome's dev panel shows exactly what is shown above. Plus if it was a unprintable characters problem then there must be some characters at least (like header length for example, which is a number and hence printable)

Comment: There quite a few good hex editors available.  The one you choose will depend on the OS you're using.  I use Bless.

Comment: it's actually an app so no specific OS :(

Comment: What I mean is, you could use a hex editor to open the mp3 file itself (apart from your application) and view the raw tag data.

Comment: oh ohkeez then that does it i guess! thanks for coming back and replying :D

Answer (score -2):

Try [this library](http://blog.nihilogic.dk/2008/08/reading-id3-tags-with-javascript.html), looks like it does what you need.

Comment: people here just love libraries.. right? :P but i am just one single step away from doing what an entire library would do with just (literally) two lines of code. :)

Comment: Plus that library just reads v1 tags and to quote the author, `Maybe I'll try to add support for the v2 tags later.`