# read mp3 id3 tags in C++

Tags: c++, mp3, id3

I try to read header of id3 tag:

```
int main() {

    union MP3Header {
        char header[10];
        struct HeaderStruct {
        char tagIndicator[3];
        char version[2];
        char flags[1];
        char size[4];
      } headerStruct;
    };


    fstream file;
    file.open("file.mp3", ios::binary || ios::in);

    MP3Header header;
    //read header of id3
    file.read(header.header, 10);


    //tag description
    char tag[4] = {0};
    strncpy(tag, header.headerStruct.tagIndicator, 3);
    cout << tag << endl;


    //get size
    string sizeTags = "";
    for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
        bitset<8> bit_set = header.headerStruct.size[i];
        sizeTags += bit_set.to_string();
    }
    cout << sizeTags << endl;
}
```

for some mp3 file size of tags is ... 1111101110110 (8054 bytes)
I think this code is wrong because size is strange.

Comment: A [simple search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3#Layout) or check of the spec would have confirmed you want 128B as standard, or 227B extended. You should use a library for something like this, such as [id3lib](http://id3lib.sourceforge.net/). The `id3` tag is at the end of the MP3 file, not the head.

Comment: id3v2 is the head.
Thanks for lib.

Comment: Your number might be okay but just needs converting because MP3 uses synch-safe integers. See this: [SynceSafe Integer conversion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5223025/why-are-there-synchsafe-integer)

Answer (score 1):

To summarise my insomniac rant...

- Go to the 7th byte
- read an integer (aka four bytes)
- Pass that amount through a "synchSafe conveter" function
- result is now correct header size (minus 10 bytes)

Well I use AS3 but I also learn from codes of C++, C#, Java, PHP, Python etc and then translating their code logic to AS3. Now I will show you how we do it in Flash (AS3) and maybe you can translate that to C++.

(for checking in ID3 v2 upwards)

```
mp3_Bytes.position = 6; //go to 7th byte (offset 6) for Header Size bytes (integer)
mp3_headerLength = readSynchsafeInt ( mp3_Bytes.readUnsignedInt() );

mp3_headerLength +=  10; //add 10 cos result always seems to be 10 bytes less
trace("Header Length  : " + mp3_headerLength);
```

and the synch Safe function to convert that read Int (four bytes) looks like:

```
private function readSynchsafeInt (synch:int):int
{
   return (synch & 127) + 128 * ((synch >> 8) & 127) + 16384 * ((synch >>16) & 127) + 2097152 * ((synch >> 24) & 127);
}
```

I did a quick look up for you and found this C++: [Why are there Synchsafe Integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5223025/why-are-there-synchsafe-integer) 
That synch Safe function looks like

```
int ID3_sync_safe_to_int( uint8_t* sync_safe )
{
    uint32_t byte0 = sync_safe[0];
    uint32_t byte1 = sync_safe[1];
    uint32_t byte2 = sync_safe[2];
    uint32_t byte3 = sync_safe[3];

    return byte0 << 21 | byte1 << 14 | byte2 << 7 | byte3;
}
```

BTW: The AS3 function just happens to be built for converting the total sum of the integer bytes whereas the C++ code sample is dealing with the actual integer bytes. Two different approaches for same result. Pick one (**AS3** convert a number gained from bytes = result or **C++** convert bytes to gain number = result)